# Adding custom field to layout for custom Quick Action

Tags: custom-field, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

Our org has a series of Quick Actions based off of custom objects, one of which is called "Log a Note." This creates a new **Note** record, with **Note** being a custom object.

I am attempting to add a custom picklist field to this Quick Action. I have already created this picklist in the **Fields and Relationships** section of the **Notes** object. This field is called **Call Type** and should only be visible when a specific selection is made on another existing custom field called **Type of Interaction**.

So this is really a two-part question:

1. Where do I edit the layout for Quick Actions? All of the documentation I've found tells me to go to Global Actions, but I'm not seeing anything there to edit this specific custom Quick Action.
2. What is the most effective way to only show this field when a user selects the correct **Type of Interaction** option? I have already created a dependency between **Type of Interaction** and **Call Type**. Is that all I need to do to hide the **Call Type** field when the other irrelevant **Type of Interactions** options are selected?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Create Record] action type to perform the record creation then it would be one of the following:

If it is a object specific quick action, then

- Go to Object > Button, Links and Actions
- Click on your action name
- You will see Edit Layout button> click on it
- Make changes and save it

If it is a global quick action, then

- Go to Global actions in setup
- Click on the action
- Click on Edit Layout button
- Make changes and save it

You will not have much flexibility to dynamically control one field visibility based on value of others. Probably you can give a try by making them dependent picklists and enable the child picklist values based on parent picklist

Check here for more details about dependent picklists - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_using_the_field_dependency_matrix.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you – I was able to find it in the Button, Links and Actions on the Account object.